# Static library having object files with same name containing static variables with same name

Tags: c, static, linker

Let's say we have this source tree:

```
.
└── src
    ├── foo
    │   ├── common.c
    │   └── foo.c
    └── bar
        ├── common.c
        └── bar.c
```

And in both `src/foo/common.c` and `src/bar/common.c` we have different `static` variables named `common_var` in both files, which obviously correspond to different variables.

All files will be compiled into a similar tree in `tmp/` (including `tmp/foo/common.s` & `tmp/bar/common.s`), later assembled into object files (including `tmp/foo/common.o` & `tmp/bar/common.o`), and all those object files will go into `lib/libfoobar.a` which will be used by some program.

Ending with this file tree:

```
.
├── lib
│   └── libfoobar.a
├── src
│   ├── foo
│   │   ├── common.c
│   │   └── foo.c
│   └── bar
│       ├── common.h
│       └── bar.hpp
└── tmp
    ├── foo
    │   ├── common.o
    │   ├── common.s
    │   ├── foo.o
    │   └── foo.s
    └── bar
        ├── common.o
        ├── common.s
        ├── bar.o
        └── bar.s
```

Is it OK, or will there be compiler/linker/any problems?

Related: [Static library having object files with same name (ar)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4907121/6872717)

The difference here is that contents may clash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Global static variables have internal linkage, so there is no way for them to be treated as the same even if there is no difference in names, mangled or otherwise.

There will be no conflict.

Comment: There will be problems if the static library is updated incrementally. Since `ar` doesn't store paths, `ar r` will replace any existing `bar.o` or `common.o` regardless of them being from `tmp/foo/` or `tmp/bar/`.